# GRE geometry question

Tags: geometry, word-problem

A swimming pool in the shape of a rectangular solid is $60$ feet long and $48$ feet wide. The bottom of the swimming pool is horizontal. To raise the water level in the pool by $\frac{1}{4}$ foot, approximately how many gallons of water must be added?($1$ cubic foot = $7.5$ gallons, rounded to the nearest $0.1$ gallon)

This question makes no sense to me, I read it over $10$ times and I'm sure it didn't mention about the height of the pool. If the question means to no providing the height, how do we find the volume?
The answer is $5400$, which seems like $\frac{60 \times 48}{4} \times 7.5 = 5400$

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing that the height of the pool is irrelevant in determining how much water is needed to raise its current height by some given amount.

Comment: Length 60, width 48, height 1/4.

Comment: You don't need to know the depth of the pool, because you're only asked about the *change* in the volume.  It's this question in disguise: if the pool is filled to a depth of $\frac14$ ft. approximately how many gallons of water does it hold?

Comment: If two quantities are in direct proportion, then their changes are also in direct proportion. This is a basic fact about proportions.

Comment: Imagine the pool is empty, how much water do you need to to fill it up to $\frac14$ ft.?